# When is wp_set_password() called or how to capture a password

Tags: security, password

***Disclaimer: I'm fully aware of the security issues created by this. This is not for production.***

Whenever a new user is registered or a password is (re)set in WordPress I'm attempting to also capture that password, encrypt it, and save it to the wp_usermeta table.

I've had success hooking into the `profile_update` action to accomplish this, but the above process only works if a password is changed from the profile page and does not account for new user registrations.

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'save_encrypted_passwords_to_usermeta' );

function save_encrypted_passwords_to_usermeta( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
        $password = $_POST['pass1'];
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'password', $password );
    }
}
```

I've looked to the pluggable function `wp_set_password()` to accomplish this and have created this muplugin which doesn't seem to work at all.

```
function wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $hash = wp_hash_password( $password );
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_pass' => $hash, 'user_activation_key' => ''), array('ID' => $user_id) );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'password', $password );
    wp_cache_delete($user_id, 'users');
}
```

I'm assuming `wp_set_password` is always called when a password is created or set so I'm not sure why my pluggable function override is not at all working.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: Reason: An Admin creates user accounts for users which do not have an email address (a fictitious catch-all address is used). The Manager for this site is responsible for remembering the user's usernames and passwords in case a user forgets but does not have the ability to change them. This is not for a public website.

Comment: Could you not generate a reset URL that the admin can hand to the users? This way they can set a new password without it being revealed or having duplicated storage, and the admin need never know what the passwords are

Comment: Sounds like a better, more secure, approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would expect `wp_user_update` to have been what gets used, but I find your motives dubious, and cannot think of a reasonable use for what you want to do

But if you really want to go down this path, use the `pre_user_pass` filter.

I would also note that there is a reason why passwords are stored as hashes, rather than encrypted, and your code has no encryption mechanism

Comment: https://gist.github.com/salipro4ever/db1a7eeb237df5834f33 is the encryption mechanism I'm using. I removed it from the code example above to simplify.

Comment: Is `pre_user_pass` and undocumented filter? I can't seem to find any references to it. Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c184d766e90f5a0499d479c79932079ae53ae3a4/wp-includes/user.php#L1206 it doesn't appear verbatim, it's a generated filter name, and not a commonly used one either

Comment: `pre_user_pass` seems to be the best possible solution to date. Can you enlighten me as to how I can pass the `$user_id` into the filter?

Comment: That information isn't passed, you'll need to figure it out via other means